# Find and display the last recordset in ADO conn

Tags: database, asp-classic, vbscript, adodb, recordset

```
<%Dim adoCon
Dim rsLogbook
Dim strSQL
Set adoCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
adoCon.Open "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("databasename.mdb")
Set rsLogbook = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strSQL = "SELECT id, OtherFieldNamesGoHere FROM TableName;"
rsLogbook.Open strSQL, adoCon
%>
```

This is the code I use to link a database to my asp page. What I'm trying to do is to display the last record of the database (which has 52 records at the moment but will change when I add more records) so the best way I feel that this would work is to find the last or max "id" which is a unique field to each record and is an auto number in the access database. But I cannot find a way to find the max id and display it. Any other better methods are also ok with me if you got any suggestions. Thanks in advance

I have tried using the following code but its giving me the error listed below

```
<%Dim adoCon
Dim rsLogbook
Dim strSQL
Set adoCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
adoCon.Open "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("databasename.mdb")
Set rsLogbook = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strSQL = "SELECT id, OtherFieldNamesGoHere FROM TableName;"
rsLogbook.CursorLocation=adUseServer
rsLogbook.Open strSQL, adoCon
rsLogbook.MoveLast
%>
```

> ADODB.Recordset error '800a0bb9'
>
> Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.

Comment: have you tried "SELECT MAX(id) as max_id, OtherFieldNamesGoHere FROM TableName;" ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an Access (or a SQL Server) database you could use a query like

```
"SELECT top 1 id, OtherFieldNamesGoHere FROM TableName ORDER by id desc"
```

Then you could just use the code in your first example without CursorLocation or MoveLast

For the record, OLEDB connection strings are generally preferred to ODBC, eg

```
"PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE=" & Server.MapPath("databasename.mdb")
```

Comment: telling me that there is a syntax error in the FROM clause. I cant seem to find fix this problem. Any help or suggestions?

Comment: Nope sorry my bad. Its was a stupid mistake and your code was perfect. Cheers mate